# EC2: is it possible to run custom JIRA container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, jira

I have an EC2 instance with Ubuntu image.

I've logged into my EC2 instance and ran the following command:

```
docker run -d --name jira -p 11111:11111 ivantichy/jira:7.9.0
```

It should start JIRA container.

It looks like it started OK:

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
b628a71a6ad2        ivantichy/jira:7.9.0   "/entrypoint.sh"    9 minutes ago       Up About a minute   8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11111->11111/tcp   jira
```

But it's not available from the browser.

I've allowed inbound traffic for this instance for `11111` port.

Do I need to setup any nginx, etc. or there are some issues with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access locally on server? Try

```
lynx http://localhost:11111
```

(Or whatever url you've set)
You can try wget, curl or telnet otherwise.
If you can connect, would look into your AWS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue was with the port number.

I just started my JIRA container on `8080` port instead of `11111` and it works fine.

Both `8080` and `11111` were opened via AWS console.